Adding a Custom Domain to Lightsail Distribution w/out having to re-verify everything
I have an AWS Lightsail distribution where I am hosting some sites for some people. I have a certificate setup with all the custom domains, and everything is verified.
When you set up the certificate, you have to add some DNS records to every single domain in order for it to work. So it's currently working with all the domains.
I have added the domain for a website I'm doing, and I want to run it through the distribution so it has SSL.
The problem is that if I go to add a new certificate,it completely replaces the old one, meaning that all the current domains already verified need to be revised.
This means that the owners of the domains that are working fine right now have to re-add DNS zones to their domains. Just so I can add my new website to the mix.
To me, this seems absolutely ridiculously stupid, and I refuse to believe that this is the only way it can work.
I can imagine this is probably only a thing with AWS Lightsail because I've already found some really dumb limitations in Lightsail that make no sense.
I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but the server is an AWS Lightsail Amazon Linux 2 instance, with a static IP attached to it.
I would like to keep using Lightsail at least for the instance. I am using Route 53 to do some DNS on other domains and point them to my distribution or Lightsail instance, so I know I can use other AWS products in conjuction with lightsail.. The price just cannot be beat.
I think I calculated the price of using EC2 in the same way, and it was way more money.
The distribution idea is pretty cool but this thing of having to create entirely new certificates with existing domains and having to reverify every single domain just to add a new one is the stupidest thing ever.
I'm simply not going to contact people and be like "Hey! You need to [insert super complicated stuff here]" because I made a new website that I want to host on my distribution.
Might as well just use Cloudflare and call it a day.. But would really like to use the Lightsail distribution so I'm open to options.
Just to clarify in case it's not clear: I want to know if it's possible to add a custom domain to a Lightsail Distribution (this is basically CloudFront but it's kind of it's own separate package I guess more n00b friendly, I dunno)
I just don't want to bother a bunch of people whose websites already work and be dependent on them doing stuff every time I add a website to my AWS Lightsail instance.

So if anyone wants to answer this question that's great, but I decided I'm just gonna use CloudFlare.
I gotta .. I'm sorry. I have to say I find it really hilarious that within 24 hours I got some dude requesting edits changing my grammar and having problems with apparently how I write things...
but then of course the question gets no answers or comments asking for anything. Gotta love it.
Maybe next time I will make sure I have a Pulitzer prize winning author write the question for me.
This is precisely why I want to leave the tech industry. People are focused on the wrong stuff.
